# Calling PDO query within a function

Tags: php, pdo

I'm 'doomsday' (mysql_ depreciation!) prepping some of my older applications that take the use of mysql_ extentions. I am currently converting them into PDO.

I use a lot of functions to make my work easy. However I cant get the $db->query within a function to work. For example I'm converting this function:

```
function GetAccount($account_id){
    $Query = mysql_query("SELECT name, balance, account_number FROM accounts WHERE id = '$account_id'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($Query) > 0){
        $Result = mysql_fetch_assoc($Query);
        return $Result;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Into this PDO function.

```
function GetAccount($account_id){
    global $db;
    $Result = $db->query("SELECT name, balance, account_number FROM accounts WHERE id = '$account_id'");
    if (count($Result) > 0){
        return $Result;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have established a PDO connection outside of this function, which works fine with queries outside of any function.

The problem for the second (PDO) function is that the $Result is empty. A var_dump returs: bool (false).

What am I forgetting/doing wrong?

Thank you :)

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question.

Comment: Cheers :)
$Result is empty.

Comment: What happens if you change the query to: $Result = $db->query("SELECT name, balance, account_number FROM accounts WHERE id = " . $account_id );  --> or better yet- use a prepared statement...

Comment: I have tested the code above and  it worked. The error must be in a different part of the code.

Comment: @ethrbunny, when I use your code, i get this array: 
   PDOStatement Object
   (
       [queryString] => SELECT name, balance, account_number FROM    accounts WHERE id = 10
   )

Comment: So just the query text - but not evaluated?

Comment: Well the variable account_id has been converted.. but it just seems like the query text. Maybe it's worth mentioning I'm only expecting one result

Comment: Am I the only one thinking the converted version is worse than the first one? Why `global`? Did you check that global `$db` is a PDO instance? `PDO::query` returns `FALSE` on failure, did you check `$db->errorInfo()` and `$db->errorCode()`?

Comment: errorInfo()and errorCode returns '00000'.

Comment: Thanks guys, but I fixed it by prepareing and executing first. I was only expecting one row. It did fetch the row if I used a foreach loop on the $Result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, new function:

```
function GetAccount($account_id){
    global $db;
    $Result = $db->prepare("SELECT name, balance, account_number FROM accounts WHERE id = '$account_id'");
$Result->execute();
$Result = $Result->fetch();

    if (count($Result) > 0){
        return $Result;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The only thing I did was :

```
$Result->prepare("query stuff");
$Result->execute();
$Result = $Result->fetch();
```